# Compiling game with Android Studio lags a lot

Tags: android, compiler-construction, android-studio, lag, aide-ide

I have a really strange problem. When I use my phone, with the 'AIDE' app, to compile my game, it runs smooth at 60fps, but then, when I use Android Studio to compile, it runs at max 40fps, and gets reaaaally laggy.

I'm using the exact same code, so that shouldn't be the problem. 
Someone who have had a similar problem? Or anyone simply know the solution? 
All help will be appreciated :)
/GuiceU

Comment: Do you run it with a debugger attached to it?

Comment: Wait whaaaat? @etienne

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution, it was my code, apparently. The problem was that I was decoding an image Drawable to Bitmap on every update. But I don't know why it worked on AIDE.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you're running it in debug mode when you're using Android Studio, which will always make execution far slower.

Comment: Okey, so... If I go Run> Run 'ProjectName', do I run it in debug mode then?